# Learning the Flute embouchure with a teardrop in the lips?

Tags: flute, physical-limitations, embouchure

I'm trying to learn the flute embouchure for an irish (wooden) flute for 2 years now. My teacher mentioned to me that because of the shape of my lips (I'm having a teardrop in the middle of my upper lip): 
[image]

This little piece of flesh always gets in the way when I try to form a small, well shaped hole that a stable air stream can be pushed through. Is there a way to learn the flute embouchure even with this condition of my lips? The "standard" embouchure with the hole directly in the middle of my lips doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I once had a student with a pronounced "cupids bow" (as they call it). He was never able to get a clear sound and eventually had to give up the flute.  But whether or not you can do it probably depends on the exact shape of your lips and their musculature.  Have you tried making the hole to one side of the middle?  My advice would be to try that for a while, and if it doesn't work, to consider another instrument.

Comment: I allready thought about this, and had hoped that somebody could provide his experience on this route :)

Comment: I've tried it myself enough to see that it might be possible.  There's historical precedent for a very different instrument, the baroque cornett, which is played with buzzed lips like a trumpet, but normally to one side where the lips are thinner.  The problems of holding an off-center embouchure without leaking are similar, though, so there might be hope for you.  You'll just have to try it out.  Best of luck to you.

Comment: I just want to add that the nay, an endblown flute, is also played asymmetrically, although sideways to the position of an Irish (or Boehm) flute.  So it's definitely worth trying.